# spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:jar:unknown was not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

These are the two pom files of parent and discovery service sitting inside parent .

```
   <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-cloud-version>2021.0.2</spring-cloud-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

        <modules>
        <module>product-service</module>
        <module>order-service</module>
        <module>inventory-service</module>
        <module>discovery-service</module>
    </modules>

    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.17.6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

and discovery service pom

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I am getting these errors .
**Non-resolvable import POM: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:${spring-cloud.version} was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt.
Another error is
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:jar:unknown was not found in **https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt.

I tried different approaches such as changing this line to

```
<version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
```

to 2021.0.2
but all this didn't help .

Answer (score 1):

Actually `pom.xml` from `spring-cloud-dependencies` does not manage `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server`. You need to specify a version yourself:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>x.x.x</version>
        </dependency>
```